# Column default value based on another property

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How to specify that a column's default value should depend on another column's value?

Say, I need a `slug` column which defaults to `id`+`title`, in the following model:

```
class Page(Base):
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  title = Column(String, nullable=False)
  slug = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
```

I tried to use `@validates`:

```
class Page(Base):
    # ...
    @validates('slug')
    def validate(self, key, slug):
        return slug or self.title  # default from another column
```

, but it does not fire when the model is constructed like this:

```
Page(title='a b c')
```

Comment: Might help http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/defaults.html#context-sensitive-default-functions

Comment: @pavel_form, thank you, it does the trick, but looks ugly without fancy wrappers :) Also, it's too low-level

Answer (score 1):

Use [events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/event.html):

```
@event.listens_for(Page, 'before_insert')
def page_defaults(mapper, configuration, target):
    # `slug` defaults to `name`
    if not target.slug:
        target.slug = target.name
```